# Message appears after writing an input in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm new to Java and i was learning inputs with Scanner but i'm getting something odd, the message of "enter a number" doesn't show, it only appears after I enter a value, here is the code and the screenshot. I'm using java 11 btw.
`

```
public class HolaMundoMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numero;
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        numero = entrada.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("The number is: "+numero);
    }
}
```

`
I tried writing the sout line before declaring Scanner but it does not work

I was expecting that first it would appear "Enter a number: " and then i could write it, but i have to write it first and then the message appears
[see image of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqqCZ.png)

Comment: Try to `System.out.flush()`.

Comment: @MCEmperor it works but i wonder how can i display a message and then enter a value?

Comment: By calling `System.out.flush()` after `System.out.print("Enter a number: ");`.

Comment: it happens the same, idk why tho

Comment: It worked fine for me. What else are you doing?

Comment: Add `entrada.nextLine();` after `numero = entrada.nextInt();` and see if that fixes it.  If it does, I'll write up why in an answer for you.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: @Popeye i'm not doing anything, i just added the flush just like James said and it happened the same, i'm using netbeans 12.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is perfectly fine, i tried running it as well and it does print first "Enter a number :" then after you enter value, it prints the next sout statement along with the value.[image], the image shows my run of the said code. Have you made any changes to java code? It's possible that you wrote the statement that takes input first then sout then you compiled it and ran it for the first time, but after changing it you forgot to compile it again using "javac completeFileName" in CMD. I have a strong feeling you just need to recompile it and then run the program using "java completeFileName". Also please note that, completeFileName is a name of path of file. if you don't compile after making changes to a file, what happens is compiler runs the previously compiled version of it, which is basically a fileName.class file(you can even see it in folder), but when you do compile again a new fileName.class is created and then used to run.

Comment: so i'm really new to java haha how do i recompile it? i used the command you said but it doesn't show anything

Comment: when the file successfully compiles, it doesnt show anything so it's a good sign. It basically means during compiling no error was found, now you can simply run the file using "java fileName"

Comment: okay so i recompiled it and when i run it with "java HolaMundoMain" it says that there is no file named like that

Comment: it should have complete file name, so if a say file exists in directory A, then file name would be "java A/HolaMundoMain.java" unless you are at the file location via commandLine(if you don't understand this second part, focus on the first and enter complete name for file) btw even the first command "javac fileName" requires complete name of file.

Comment: jesus christ it was a really dumb error. I didn't wrote the .java extension (but it seems kinda odd to me since in all examples i have seen they don't use it to run the code), in fact the code is fine, i think it may be a netbeans glitch or something. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: i have not used netbeans, but if you are not restricted to using netbeans intellij does a really good job if you plan to work with java. Does all the heavy lifting for you, btw if this helped please do mark it as an answer that would help me :)

Comment: I do not think compilation has anything to with your issue. I wonder how NetBeans console behave. try compiling this way `javac HolaMundoMain.java` and then execute it as `java HolaMundoMain`

Comment: thanks, i'm definitely gonna use it, and i just accepted this as an answer, i tried marking it as useful but since i just created this account i need reputation to cast a vote, but it said the feedback has been recorded

Comment: @Popeye when using CMD it works fine using those commands, but when i use the "run" button in netbeans it happens the problem. I just used intellij and it worked fine, so i really don't know what was the problem when running it with netbeans

Comment: @NicolasBedoya, I guess, NetBeans are not upto the job. Try switching to JetBrain (intellij) or Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

The code it's working on my end. Try to compile it using `javac HolaMundoMain.java` and run with `java -cp . HolaMundoMain`.
[Image of the code running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0YVT.png)